# Default CSS ovveriden the styles applied in HTML

Tags: html, css, gwt, user-interface

[image: Firefox screenshot]

Here, I am facing another problem with CSS.

My HTML string is coming from database and adding to DOM with HTML Object.

```
new HTML(result.getResponseObject().getStringResult());
```

That string contains some HTML tables and  have `border="1"`, that has been overridden by default CSS (you can see that in Firebug), where as the border applied in HTML like `border="1"`

How to tell that the applied styles are in `HTML`, not from any CSS file (or did I miss something in my code)?

I tried with `1px solid !important`; it's still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you could do something like this:

```
table[border] {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

This will select any table that has a html border property eg:

```
<table border="1">
```

but will ignore those that don't

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K2ZLQ/)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the `border` attributed to begin with? In HTML5, it's meant only to indicate that `<table>` is being used to draw an actual table, rather than just for layout. If you want to specify a table border, you should use something like 3rror404's solution (although I would explicitly use `table[border="1"]` as the selector to avoid problems if you also have tables with `border="0"` anywhere in the document.